# WSARecv ways to know if operation completes

Tags: winapi, internet-explorer-11, winsock, windows-10, api-hook

In my app (not a malware) I inspect browsers' network traffic by hooking Windows API calls.

Works fine in all browsers in all Windows versions... Except Internet Explorer 11 under Windows 10.

The problem is that `WSARecv` returns `WSA_IO_PENDING`, but none of known by me methods to get notified about the operation completion are used.

- `WSAOVERLAPPED::hEvent` set to 0.
- `lpCompletionRoutine` is 0 also.
- `WSAGetOverlappedResult` is never called.
- `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` and `GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx` are not called also.
- `CreateThreadpoolIo` is not called.

So, what does IE11 use under Windows 10?

Comment: Why not use [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org) instead of hooking APIs?

Comment: "*So, what does IE11 use under Windows 10?*" - you would have to ask Microsoft.  Or maybe Raymond Chen will chime in with one of his famous insights about the internal details.

Comment: As far as I know winpcap requires admin rights.

Comment: Only to install the driver. After that, any user can use winpcap for capturing packets without needing admin rights. This was covered on the Winpcap-users mailing list: [Running as non-admin](http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-users/2009-January/002997.html)

Comment: I'll consider switching to winpcap (or something) else in case I fail to fix the problem in the current solution. It's unwanted thing, btw. It will require more time, etc.

Comment: Hmm... Winpcap is not suitable at all. Because it seems it does not allow to know which packets belongs to which process. I want to inspect only a target browser's process. Not all processes. Not all browsers.

Comment: The header of each packet will tell you the transport protocols (IPv4, IPv6, TCP, UDP) and source/destination IP/Port pairs. For TCP packets, you can find the associated process ID by looking for the IP/Port pairs in Windows' TCP tables via [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx) (IPv4) and [`GetTcp6Table2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx) (IPv6). There are UDP tables available via `GetUdpTable()` (IPv4) and `GetUdp6Table()` (IPv6) but they do not provide process IDs. Browsers do not use UDP anyway.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev, Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Ajay, No, I did not.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev, Did you get the solutin now?